# GoogleDrive integration

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have integrated Google Drive in my android app. I tested it on two devices - Samsung Galaxy S Advance and Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300), both with the same android version 2.3.6.

On the first device everything works, but on the second one I get an exception 
No Activity found to handle

`Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT (has extras) }`

when I call that

`context.startActivityForResult(mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);`

Does anybody know what can be wrong?

Comment: You should consult this link to ensure each phone has the latest google play to handle this intent: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure

Comment: Thank you, I updated google play and now works.

Comment: This question can be rephrased such that anyone encountering using that specific intent can use my advice to solve their issue.

Comment: @JustinBreitfeller you can edit that question as you would like